# GetUserDetails error Error 27 The name 'IMGUserLabel' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I need to get the users name displayed next to the Users picture. The Picture works great however the IMGUserLabel says it not in context. . can you help me solve this?

```
public void GetUserDetails(int id)
{
    string getUserDetail = "Select ID,Email,Name,Country,Convert(varchar (20), RegisterDate, 106) RegisterDate,Convert(varchar (20), LastLogin, 106) LastLogin ,Description,ImageName FROM [User] where Id='" + id + "'";



    dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserDetail);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        IMGUserLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        NameLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        UserImage.ImageUrl = "~/UserImage/" + dt.Rows[0]["ImageName"].ToString();
        lblCreated.Text = dt.Rows[0]["RegisterDate"].ToString();
        LabelLastLogin.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LastLogin"].ToString();
        lblCreated.Text = dt.Rows[0]["RegisterDate"].ToString();
        LabelAboutMe.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
    }
}
```

///////////// .Aspx //////////

```
     <a href="<%#GetUserDetails(GetUser(Int Id)%>">

             <asp:Label ID="IMGUserLabel" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Names="Segoe UI" 
                Font-Size="Larger" ForeColor="White"
             src="<%#GetUserDetails(GetUser(Int Id)%>">

             </asp:Label>

              </a>
```

he name 'IMGUserLabel' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: Care to tell us exactly what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: Your cods references IMGuserLabel but your tag says IMGNameLabel...

Comment: man, there is a lot wrong here, but just as a start, notice that getHREF() and GetSrc() have return statements in them, while GetUserDetails does not.

Comment: okay, Since my IMGUserLabel is next to my Picture the Label is caused to be Not in context so i tryed to add <%#GetUserDetails(GetUser.(Int Id);)%> to find the imguserlabel but it didnt work can you try to  rewrite is so it can find IMGUserLabel?

Comment: @Jason GetUserDetails (poorly named) does not return anything - it is a void function (procedure) that seems to set up several of the controls on the page.

Comment: You've still got a syntax error: `GetUserDetails(GetUser(Int Id)` is not valid syntax, and GetUserDetails doesn;t return anything anyways.

Comment: what would i write for it become a valid syntax?

Comment: Is your ASPX snippet that contains `IMGUserLabel` within a repeater or other container control?

Comment: Okay All need to fix is The name 'IMGUserLabel' does not exist in the current context? , i have erased the <%#GetUserDetails(GetUser(Int Id)%>"> . im Guessing it cant find the label so it need another way of finding it?

Answer (score 1):

You've got at least 2 problems that I can see:

1) You've named the image as `IMGNameLabel` in your markup but are trying to reference it as `IMGUserLabel`

2) `GetUserDetails(GetUser.(Int Id);)` is not valid c# syntax.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do here since `GetUserDetails` does not return a value.

Also it's preferred to copy/paste the actual code in your question that screenshots of your code.  SO will format your code nicely.  Feel free to add comments within the code to indicate here the problem is.

Comment: Okay All need to fix is The name 'IMGUserLabel' does not exist in the current context? , i have erased the <%#GetUserDetails(GetUser(Int Id)%>"> . i am Guessing it cant find the label so it need another way of finding it?

Comment: Because it is within the container, not directly on the page.  The _best_ way is to create that container as a `UserControl` and expose `IMGUserLabel` as a property of that user control.  An alternative would be to call `container.FindControl("IMGUserLabel")` to get a reference to the label.

Answer (score 0):

Your code references IMGUserLabel but your tag says IMGNameLabel...

Rename one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside GetUserDetail markup seems buggy... what is GetUser.(Int Id)?

Comment: Okay, i have renamed the labels and corrected my code reference. I also changed <%#GetUserDetails(GetUser.(Int Id);)%>"> to <%#GetUserDetails(GetUser(Int Id)%>"> and the IMGUserLabel still doesn't exist?